# Xorg starts on display :1 at reboot

Tags: rhel, x11, xorg

When rebooting a RedHat Linux, screen sometimes gets blank (=black). This is because Xorg launched itself on a display `:1` instead of the expected `:0` display. It is possible to connect via ssh, or open a terminal via Ctrl-Alt-F2.

Generally, rebooting one more time brings back the display.

=> Any clue on how to fix this?

Comment: Normally you can switch to Xorg's VT via Ctrl+Alt+F8 if its display is `:1` or Ctrl+Alt+F7 for `:0`.

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks! But why does (sometimes) the display change to :1 instead of :0 ?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that some instance of Xorg might have crashed, leaving behind its lock file, `/tmp/.X0-lock`. Then, when a new instance is launched, it notices this lock file and goes on with another display number. On reboot the `/tmp` directory is cleared, so Xorg may start with display `:0`.

I'm not sure why you're not at this new instance's VT though. You can manually switch to Xorg's VT via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> if its display is `:1` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> for `:0`.

To examine what happened to the Xorg at display `:0`, see its log file(s) `/var/log/Xorg.0.log*`.

Comment: Very nice explaination! +1 Thank you. Please let me some time (a few days) to check this when returning at work next week.